# how to keep logged in user in the current page and not to let him go to home from the address bar?

Tags: python, html, django

I want to keep the logged in user in the current page that he is viewing and not allow him to visit the home page again without loggin out either by pressing the backbutton provided by the browser or form the address bar.
Is there any decorator that i can use, i tried to write on form a tutorial but i couldn't figure out how to keep the user in the current page. If there is any auto logout method availble please suggest me.

**decorators.py**

```
def unauthenticated_user(view_func):
    def wrapper_func(request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            return redirect('current_page')
        else:
            return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

    return wrapper_func
```

**views.py**

```
@unauthenticated_user
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')
```

Comment: you're doing it correctly already? redirecting authenticated users when they try visit login page is the best way i think

Comment: But I cannot make them stay in the current page as I have categories based on which their respective pages are displayed. @Henty

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. You cant stop people from changing urls etc so handle it by redirecting to the page you want them to go too, i imagine a home page of sorts

Comment: @henty yes sir, I got confused a little bit. I have started redirecting them to the login page. This solved my problem.

Comment: good one, good luck